# Caching EJB entities using JBoss Hibernate cache (JBoss-5.0.0.GA)

Tags: hibernate, caching, jpa, jboss5.x

My applications very often queries database for rarely-changed data. So I've decided to optimize it using cached EJB entities as desribed in:
http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/tutorial/1.0.7/html/Caching_EJB3_Entities.html

However, when I take a look at hibernate sql logs (hibernate.show_sql = true) I can still see the same number of queries hitting database as without cache configured. Here is my persistence.xml file:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
      version="1.0">


      <persistence-unit name="myds">
         <jta-data-source>java:/myds</jta-data-source>

         (...) classes definitions
         <class>com.my.class.MyEntityOne</class>
         (...)

         <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.ejb.transaction.JoinableCMTTransactionFactory"/>


            <!-- 2nd level cache -->                                       
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.jbc2.JndiMultiplexedJBossCacheRegionFactory"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.region.jbc2.cachefactory" value="java:CacheManager"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.region.jbc2.cfg.entity" value="mvcc-entity"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.region.jbc2.cfg.query" value="local-query"/>
         </properties>
      </persistence-unit>
```

All my JPA entities are annotated with:

```
@Cache (usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
```

Maybe a little hint will be that when I shut down server the following exception can be seen in logs:

> org.hibernate.cache.CacheException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cache not in STARTED state!
>             at org.hibernate.cache.jbc2.BasicRegionAdapter.destroy(BasicRegionAdapter.java:243)
>             at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.close(SessionFactoryImpl.java:813)
>             at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.close(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:46)
>             at org.jboss.jpa.deployment.ManagedEntityManagerFactory.destroy(ManagedEntityManagerFactory.java:93)
>             at org.jboss.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitDeployment.stop(PersistenceUnitDeployment.java:343)
>             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>             at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)

Should I do some additional setup?
Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
Piotr

Comment: Are you trying to enable the 2nd level entity cache, or the query cache?  The two are quite distinct. The queries themselves have to explicitly say they want to use the query cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caching queries (as skaffman suggested):

```
Query query = manager.createQuery("SELECT i FROM ....");
query.setHint("org.hibernate.cacheable", true);
```

In case of entities, I noticed, that it not enough to annotate all entities with @Cache. If your entity has reference to other entities (annotated with @Cache), you must also include this annotation on a top of a referencing field:

```
@Cache (usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
@Entity
public class EntityA {
  @Cache (usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
  private Set<EntityB> entitiesB;
}

@Cache (usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
@Entity
public class EntityB {
}
```

I don't know if it's general rule, but in my case, after I've added these annotations, everything started to work as expected.